# Unable to start Apache server (2.4) on Windows system (64 bit) using mod_jk connector

Tags: apache, mod-jk

1. Downloaded Tomcat7 binaries for 64 bit
2. Downloaded Apache server (2.4.X) binaries for 64 bit
3. Downloaded mod_jk.so binaries for win64 and placed that into "D:/apache24/modules" folder
4. Created "workers.properties" and "mod_jk.conf" files and copied that files into "D:/Tomcat_7.0/conf" folder
5. put "Include D:/Tomcat_7.0/conf/mod_jk.conf" line at the end of "httpd.conf" file of "D:/apache24/conf/extra" folder

   mod_jk.conf

   ```
   LoadModule jk_module D:/apache24/modules/mod_jk.so

   JkWorkersFile D:/Tomcat_7.0/conf/workers.properties

   JkLogFile D:/Tomcat_7.0/logs/mod_jk.log

   JkLogLevel info
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

   JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

   JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

   JkMount /ws ajp13
   JkMount /ws/* ajp13
   ```

   workers.properties

   ```
   worker.list=ajp13
   worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
   worker.ajp13.host=localhost
   worker.ajp13.port=8009
   worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
   worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
   worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
   worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
   worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
   ```
6. Accordingly I have modified the server.xml also in Tomcat7
7. now, when I run the below command on command prompt I am getting the syntax error as shown below:

   ```
    D:\apache24\bin> httpd -k install
   ```

   > httpd: Syntax error on line "Include D:/Tomcat_7.0/conf/mod_jk.conf" of D:/apache24/conf/extra/httpd.conf : Cannot load D:/apache24/modules/mod_jk.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you can't load .so modules on Windows. Also not about programming and asking for help "asap" is not polite unless you're willing to pay for it.

Comment: You are not wright, mod_jk for Apache HTTPD in windows is actually with `.so` extension. Otherwise, make it wright you have downloaded the correct mod_jk version that matches your httpd version. If I'm not wrong, the last version for HTTPD 2.4 in Windows can be downloaded from this link: http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-windows-x86_64-httpd-2.4.x.zip

Comment: I am using same type of configuration, only my software version are different. I am using Tomcat 9, Apache Httpd 2.4.33, mod_jk 1.2.40 (for httpd 2.4.x). But still I am getting the same issue:   httpd: Syntax error on line 534 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:\\Apache24\\modules\\mod_jk-1.2.43\\mod_jk.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

Download the correct version of mod : https://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/ from here for windows64 and it should start working